# Critical Numbers Problems

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, pi

Okay so I found the critical number no problem, it being `cos x=-1/2`, but on my answer sheet it says that the critical numbers are `2pi/3` or `4pi/3`. How are they getting these numbers?

Comment: These are the two numbers between $0$ and $2\pi$ whose cosine is $-1/2$. To see that there are two, graph the cosine function.

Comment: Well, those are angles for which cosine is equal to -1/2.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x=-\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\implies \cos^{-1}(\cos x)=x=\cos^{-1}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{2\pi}{3},\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\text{ on graphing.}$$